# How to create a button from a new class?

Tags: java, android

I created a new class which has Button btn with in. But I can not initialize the btn Ojbect in my constructor.

```
class Character {
Button btn;
Character()
{
    btn = new Button();
}
}
```

I've tried adding this, and Play.this but both of them give me error.
How can I make it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: A Button (all views) require you to pass a Context to the constructor-  there is no 0 value constructor.

Comment: yes I know, I have tried this as usually but it gave me an error, then I tried Play.this which is another class that extends Activity but still same error

Comment: Play.this would only work if Character is a non-static  subclass of Play.  Otherwise there's no parent Play object to get the this of.

Comment: no Character is not a subclass of Play

Comment: Then Play.this can't be used.  You'll have to pass a Context into the character constructor.  Although its a definite warning sign to have any class other than a fragment, activity, or adapter creating a view- especially one that doesn't already need a Context.  It makes me think your architecture is likely a bit convoluted.

Comment: ahhhh, it was supposed to get the context from the Play class. Thanks a lot now the error dissapeared. By the way I am still newbie and may be my architecture is bad but I won't give up until I get really stuck. Thanks once again

Comment: Don't take that as an insult-  we all code ourselves into corners and need to refactor sometimes.  It was a friendly warning that you may be doing that.  Of course sometimes the best way to learn is to bull ahead until you're stuck then figure out what you can do better.